# Unpack binary data got require string argument error

Tags: python, binary-data

I'm trying to unpack binary data from .txt and the code is following

```
import struct 

with open("example.txt",'rb') as file :
    fileContent = file.read()

var = struct.unpack('dd',fileContent)
print var
```

then I got an error says

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 16
```

My code of writing the binary text file is as following

```
self._example = open('C:/TPC_App/test_23/example.txt','w')
self._example.write(struct.pack('dd', x, y))
```

where x and y are doubles like this

```
0.006002 -3.55046514667e-07
```

My question is, what would be the proper way of reading binary data?

and why am I got the error says the unpack requires a string argument ?

Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn't you be writing the file as binary `wb`?

Comment: And you should also be using a `with` to write the file.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks, I changed w to wb , and it still gives me the same error ..

Comment: @snakecharmerb I think I got it, I change the line  fileContent = file.read(16), and it read the first value, Thanks for that hint !